# Use React hook to implement a self-increment counter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

The code is here: https://codesandbox.io/s/nw4jym4n0

```
export default ({ name }: Props) => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setCounter(counter + 1);
    }, 1000);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  });

  return <h1>{counter}</h1>;
};
```

The problem is each `setCounter` trigger re-rendering so the interval got reset and re-created. This might looks fine since the state(counter) keeps incrementing, however it could freeze when combining with other hooks.

What's the correct way to do this? In class component it's simple with a instance variable holding the interval.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

You could give an empty array as second argument to `useEffect` so that the function is only run once after the initial render. Because of how closures work, this will make the `counter` variable always reference the initial value. You could then use the function version of `setCounter` instead to always get the correct value.

**Example**

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setCounter(counter => counter + 1);
    }, 1000);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, []);

  return <h1>{counter}</h1>;
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

A more versatile approach would be to create a new custom hook that stores the function in a [`ref`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-there-something-like-instance-variables) and only creates a new interval if the `delay` should change, [like Dan Abramov does in his great blog post **"Making setInterval Declarative with React Hooks"**](https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/#just-show-me-the-code).

**Example**

```js
const { useState, useEffect, useRef } = React;

function useInterval(callback, delay) {
  const savedCallback = useRef();

  // Remember the latest callback.
  useEffect(() => {
    savedCallback.current = callback;
  }, [callback]);

  // Set up the interval.
  useEffect(() => {
    let id = setInterval(() => {
      savedCallback.current();
    }, delay);
    return () => clearInterval(id);
  }, [delay]);
}

function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  useInterval(() => {
    setCounter(counter + 1);
  }, 1000);

  return <h1>{counter}</h1>;
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Did you really need to save it here with useRef? Couldn't you just call the callback straight without referencing it?

Answer (score 16):

As [another answer by @YangshunTay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53395147/use-react-hook-to-implement-a-self-increment-counter/53397437#53397437) already shows, it's possible to make it `useEffect` callback run only once and work similarly to `componentDidMount`. In this case it's necessary to use state updater function due to the limitations imposed by function scopes, otherwise updated `counter` won't be available inside `setInterval` callback.

The alternative is to make `useEffect` callback run on each counter update. In this case `setInterval` should be replaced with `setTimeout`, and updates should be limited to `counter` updates:

```
export default ({ name }: Props) => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      setCounter(counter + 1);
    }, 1000);

    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
    };
  }, [counter]);

  return <h1>{counter}</h1>;
};
```

Comment: This is not ideal as you will keep run `setTimeout` on every render and seems kind of unnecessary.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this. Performance concerns are nonexistent. Recursive setTimeout is a common replacement for setInterval in JS when it's justified. State updater function looks fine in setInterval in this particular case, i.e. for simple increment. This would be very different if several states were involved.

Answer (score 15):

The correct way to do this would be to run the effect only once. Since you only need to run the effect once because during mounting, you can pass in an empty array as a second argument to achieve.

However, you will need to change `setCounter` to use the previous value of `counter`. The reason is because the callback passed into `setInterval`'s closure only accesses the `counter` variable in the first render, it doesn't have access to the new `counter` value in the subsequent render because the `useEffect()` is not invoked the second time; `counter` always has the value of 0 within the `setInterval` callback.

Like the `setState` you are familiar with, state hooks have two forms: one where it takes in the updated state, and the callback form which the current state is passed in. You should use the second form and read the latest state value within the `setState` callback to ensure that you have the latest state value before incrementing it.

```js
function Counter() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = React.useState(0);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      setCounter(prevCount => prevCount + 1); // <-- Change this line!
    }, 1000);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(timer);
    };
  }, []); // Pass in empty array to run effect only once!

  return (
    <div>Count: {counter}</div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Counter />, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: how to stop the incremention?

Comment: Save `timer` as a ref and manually invoke `clearInterval(timer)` somewhere