# With react hooks set state, in what cases I have to pass a function to set state?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

here is my code:

```
function Tiker() {
  var [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    var timerID = setInterval(_=>
      setCount(count=>count+1)//setCount(count+1) wont work
    , 1000);

    return function cleanup() {
      clearInterval(timerID);
    };
  }, []);
  return <div>
      this is ticker   
      <button onClick={() => 
        setCount(count + 1)//setCount(count+1) does work
      }>up </button>
      {count}
      </div>
}
```

By trial and error I discovered that if I use setCount from within setinterval callback, I have to pass a callback to the set state rather than just value.

its not the case if I call from onclick.

Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that using a callback is the easiest way to change state when called from setInterval. as evident by Frodor comment above and from https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the second argument of `useEffect`

```
useEffect(() => {
    var timerID = setInterval(_=>
        setCount(count=>count+1)//setCount(count+1) wont work
    , 1000);

    return function cleanup() {
        clearInterval(timerID);
    };
}, []);
```

It is empty array (`[]`). It defines [list of dependencies](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect) for hook. As it empty, it means that hook is not dependent from any value of state or props. So `count` variable is consumed on first call of `useEffect` and than stays stale.

To correct this you should either completely remove second argument of `useEffect` or make array contain `[count]`.

Callback is working as it receives previous count value as first argument.

So correct code will look like

```
function Tiker() {
    var [count, setCount] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        var timerID = setInterval(_=>
            setCount(count + 1)
        , 1000);

        return function cleanup() {
            clearInterval(timerID);
        };
    }, [count]);  // Put variable that useHook depends on

    return <div>
        this is ticker   
        <button onClick={() => 
            setCount(count + 1) //setCount(count+1) does work
        }>up </button>
        {count}
    </div>
}
```

Comment: the reason that i used an empty array is tell react to call the setinterval and clear interval just once in the mount/unmount cycle. (I followed this advice: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53395147/use-react-hook-to-implement-a-self-increment-counter ) .

when I add count to that array, the functions are called on every update of the component which occurs every second

Comment: This case you should use callback in `setCount` as you already did.